# How to make copy of contacts from one account into another account?

Tags: android, copy, contacts, account

This question is related to android contacts & accounts.
   How do I make a copy of contacts from one account into another account? 
   For sample, the contacts in account A is person_a, person_b, person_c, person_d; but there are none in account B. How to make copy of person_a, person_b, person_c, person_d in account B. Contacts in account A are not deleted.
   Thanks.

BR
Shawn

Comment: by account do you mean Google account?

Comment: Firstly, thank you, fredley. Not only Google account. There maybe multiple accounts in contacts. My app created one account, I want to copy contacts from the phone account into my account.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do that as well and the only solution is to develop your own ASyncTask to do so. It is a long work as you have to manage the possible duplication, hidden contacts and so on...